# sum up every 12 months in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a table calculating the installments. in that table i'm saving all the data recording to that. For example if i'm calculating for 60 installments and saving all the data,so it is like 60 months. so now i need to sum up the value of one column for every 12 months. sometimes v start paying the installments from the middle of the year also.

my DB looks like this.the highlighted column must sum up for every 12 months. two images are one table only [image: the highlighted column must sum up for every 12 months]

suppose i have 30 installments from starting on jun 2012.suppose i started paying installment from jun 2012 then should sum up the installments from jun 2012 to may 2013. v can't use group by year. i must sum up like this ................................................................................‌​
sum jun 2012 to may 2013
sum jun 2013 to may 2014
sum jun 2014 to nov 2014 ( only 6 months left)

[image]

Comment: Please include a consumable sample data in a form of fiddle.

Comment: `..Sum(amount).. group by year(installment_month)`

Comment: suppose i have 30 installments from  starting on jun 2012.suppose i started paying installment from jun 2012 then should sum up the installments from jun 2012 to may 2013. v can't use group by year. i must sum up like this .................................................................................................................sum jun 2012 to may 2013                                                                         sum jun 2013 to may 2014                                                                             sum jun 2014 to nov 2014 ( only 6 months left)

Comment: Please post the table structure.

Comment: already i put the images Felix Pamittan. thos two images are one table

Comment: Yeah, but there is no column name on the first table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate a group of 12 months:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY InstallmentMonth) - 1)/ 12
    FROM your_table
)
SELECT
    SUM(InteresetPerInstallment)
FROM  Cte
GROUP BY RN
```

Comment: thanks a lot Felix Pamittan. It's Working :)                                                      small doubt in this query. Why you decremented by 1

Comment: small doubt in this query. Why you decremented by 1

Comment: So that the grouping will for 12 months. Without the decrement, you'll only get 11 months